# Unable to install Greenlet for Flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.10

I am trying to install **greenlet** for **flask-sqlalchemy** but I am getting error all the times.
I also tried by downloading the file and install into the virtual environment created, but no progress with it.

Can anyone help me with this??

Here is the error I am getting:

```
(env) PS W:\Codes\Python\Flask-App> pip install flask-sqlalchemy              
Collecting flask-sqlalchemy
  Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=2.2 in w:\codes\python\flask-app\env\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from flask-sqlalchemy) (2.3.2)
Collecting SQLAlchemy>=1.4.18 (from flask-sqlalchemy)
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-2.0.15-py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.3.3 in w:\codes\python\flask-app\env\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from Flask>=2.2->flask-sqlalchemy) (2.3.4)    
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.1.2 in w:\codes\python\flask-app\env\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from Flask>=2.2->flask-sqlalchemy) (3.1.2)      
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.1.2 in w:\codes\python\flask-app\env\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from Flask>=2.2->flask-sqlalchemy) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.1.3 in w:\codes\python\flask-app\env\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from Flask>=2.2->flask-sqlalchemy) (8.1.3)       
Requirement already satisfied: blinker>=1.6.2 in w:\codes\python\flask-app\env\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from Flask>=2.2->flask-sqlalchemy) (1.6.2)     
Collecting typing-extensions>=4.2.0 (from SQLAlchemy>=1.4.18->flask-sqlalchemy)
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting greenlet!=0.4.17 (from SQLAlchemy>=1.4.18->flask-sqlalchemy)
  Using cached greenlet-2.0.2.tar.gz (164 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in w:\codes\python\flask-app\env\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from click>=8.1.3->Flask>=2.2->flask-sqlalchemy) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in w:\codes\python\flask-app\env\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.1.2->Flask>=2.2->flask-sqlalchemy) (2.1.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
  Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [90 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\leakcheck.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_contextvars.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_cpp.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_extension_interface.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_gc.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_generator.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_generator_nested.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_greenlet.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_greenlet_trash.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_leaks.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_stack_saved.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_throw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_tracing.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\test_weakref.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      copying src\greenlet\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\tests
      running egg_info
      writing src\greenlet.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\greenlet.egg-info\dependency_links.txt  
      writing requirements to src\greenlet.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\greenlet.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\greenlet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'benchmarks\*.json'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'      
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
      adding license file 'AUTHORS'
      writing manifest file 'src\greenlet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet.cpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_allocator.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_compiler_compat.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_cpython_compat.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_exceptions.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_greenlet.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_internal.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_refs.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_slp_switch.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_thread_state.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_thread_state_dict_cleanup.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\greenlet_thread_support.hpp -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\slp_platformselect.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet
      copying src\greenlet\platform\setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_alpha_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_amd64_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm32_ios.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm64_masm.asm -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm64_masm.obj -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_arm64_msvc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_csky_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      copying src\greenlet\platform\switch_mips_unix.h -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\greenlet\platform
      error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
  Running setup.py clean for greenlet
Failed to build greenlet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for greenlet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am having Python 3.10.11, and I downloaded the greenlet file with version cp310. But its still not recognizing it saying:

```
(env) PS W:\Codes\Python\Flask-App> pip install "C:\Users\Supayan Das\Downloads\greenlet-2.0.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl"
ERROR: greenlet-2.0.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: Are you sure that `pip` is using Python 3.10? Are you sure your virtual environment is using Python 3.10? Are you sure your computer is using an Intel 64-bit processor, 64-bit Python, and 64-bit version of Windows, and not, for example, 32-bit Windows, 32-bit Python, or an ARM processor?

Comment: When you run `python` from the command line (nothing else), what is the first line that appears?

Comment: yes pip using 3.10, virtual environment using python 3.10, and yes everything is 64 bits, amd processor not intel, thats the difference. @MattDMo

Comment: Intel and AMD processors are functionally identical from an architecture standpoint. IA-64, intel_x64, x64, x86_64, and AMD64 all mean the same thing. As far as your problem is concerned, though, try `pip install wheel`, then try installing greenlet again, both with your downloaded `.whl` file and via `pip install greenlet`. Where did you download the `.whl` file from?

Comment: I downloaded it from pypi @MattDMo

Comment: The ```.whl``` file shows that its ```not a supported wheel for the platform``` and ```pip install greenlet``` shows that ```error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')``` @MattDMo

Comment: Hmm. I don't know why the `.whl` isn't installing. From the full error message, it looks like your system is set up to use some form of the MINGW toolchain, so that's what it may mean when throwing the `--plat-name` error. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what else I can suggest without having access to your computer...

Answer (score 0):

You can try install it globally if virtual enviroment don't work

or

You can try solve this error by changing (reinstaling) python version that support the project from official Python official website resource. Maybe your active pip in the operating system comes from another aplication (for instance Inkscape, QGIS)).

check the current version of the active pip in the operating system:

```
pip -V
```

The result could be something like this

```
C:\Users\Personal>pip -V
pip 22.1.2 from C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

C:\Users\Personal>
```

As you see This pip comes from `from C:\Program Files\Inkscape`

You can get more detailed help from this [link](http://www.dark-hamster.com/application/how-to-solve-error-message-python-setup-py-egg_info-did-not-run-successfully-distutils-errors-distutilsplatformerror-plat-name-must-be-one-of-win32-win-amd64-win-arm32-win-arm64/)